# approximations of finite series of $e^x$

Tags: sequences-and-series, problem-solving

Are there any common identies or rules for approximating finite summations of $e^x$? Specifically looking at why $\frac{2\delta}{e^\delta}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}e^{-2\delta i} \approx 1 - e^{-2 \delta n}$ for $\delta \ll 1$

Answer (score 1):

This is just the [geometric progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Geometric_series):
$$\sum_{i=0}^N r^i = \frac{1-r^{N+1}}{1-r}$$
with $r = e^{-2\delta}$ and $N=n-1$. Note that
$$\frac{2\delta}{e^\delta} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (e^{-2\delta})^i = \frac{2\delta}{e^\delta} \frac{1-(e^{-2\delta})^n}{1-e^{-2\delta}}$$
now use the fact that $\delta < 1$.

Comment: So we also have the approximation $(1+x) \approx e^x$ when $\lvert x\rvert \ll 1$ so $1 - e^{-2\delta} \approx 1 - (1 - 2\delta) = 2\delta$, and $e^\delta \approx 1$ and we have our answer. Thank you very much

Comment: Absolutely fine! You're welcome. If my answer was helpful for you, just accept it.